# Graphics Unusable With fglrx

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I'm having graphics problems with a 1 day old install of 12.10 on a Sony Vaio VGN-FW139E with a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400.

I could not get my HDMI display to be recognized, so I tried installing the proprietary drivers through the Software Center.

When I rebooted however, the resolution had been send to 1024x768, the launcher cannot be seen or accessed, and terminals will not appear.

I can get to the system settings menu by right clicking the desktop, but cannot launch any other applications.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release notes suggest it does not support Sony Vaio:
http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystSoftwareSuiteVersion1211BetaReleaseNotes.aspx

Comment: That could be part of the problem. I have downgraded to 12.04, proprietary works fine there.